# Unrefrenced function Error in Angular/Nodejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework, mean-stack

I am having issue with a function being attached to a button through onclick(). I have used UI-routing to attach a controller to a html page with ionic tags. Here is the code snippet --

**app.js**

```
var havyakkaMaduve  = angular.module('havyakka_maduve',     ['ionic','ngStorage','ngCordova','ngCordovaOauth'])

havyakkaMaduve.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider

  // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
    .state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'homePage.html',
    controller: 'LoginController'
  })
    .state('registration', {
    url:'/reg',
    templateUrl:'templates/registration.html',
    controller:'UserDetailsController'
    });

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/reg");

    });

havyakkaMaduve.controller("UserDetailsController",["$scope","$http",  function($scope,$http) {
  console.log("Inside userDetails Controller");
  $scope.submitDetails = function () {
    console.log("Submitting details");
    $http.get("/test").success(function(response){
      console.log("Test success");
    });
  };


}]);
```

**Registration.html**

```
<ion-pane>
  <ion-content class="padding">
    <div class="reg_list">
      <label class="item item-input">
        <span class="input-label">Full Name</span>
        <input type="text" required>
  </label>
  <label class="item item-input">
    <span class="input-label">Mane</span>
    <input type="text" required>
  </label>
  <label class="item item-input">
    <span class="input-label">Gotra</span>
    <input type="text" required>
  </label>
  <label class="item item-input">
    <span class="input-label">Date</span>
    <input type="date" required>
  </label>
  <label class="item item-input">
    <span class="input-label">Education</span>
    <input type="text" required>
  </label>
  <label class="item item-input">
    <span class="input-label">Occupation</span>
    <input type="text" required>
  </label>
  <label class="item item-input">
    <span class="input-label">Father's Name</span>
    <input type="text" required>
  </label>
  <label class="item item-input">
    <span class="input-label">Mother's Name</span>
    <input type="text" required>
  </label>
  <label class="item item-input">
    <span class="input-label">Current Location</span>
    <input type="text" required>
  </label>
  <label class="item item-input">
    <span class="input-label">Upload Image</span>
    <input type="file" required>
  </label>
  <label class="item item-input">
    <span class="input-label">Digital Identity</span>
    <input type="url" required>
  </label>
  <label class="item item-input">
    <span class="input-label">About Me</span>
    <input type="text">
  </label>
</div>
<button class="button button-block button-positive" onclick="submitDetails">Submit</button>
<div>
</div>
```

Somebody please tell me where I am going wrong as I don't see any issue here yet I get "ReferenceError: submitDetails is not defined". I see the issue when the "Submit" button is clicked upon.Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use ng-click instead of onclick, and the function should be called with parentheses:

```
<button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="submitDetails()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Thanks. But now it isn't logging in my next console.log() output inside the submitDetails function and even the get request is not done.

Comment: Sorry I didn't catch that second part.  Updated my answer!